# Read GET/POST parameters in apex class when service is called from external client

Tags: rest-api, apexrest, post

I am new to salesforce. I created an apex class and exposed it as a Rest service. I want to post some parameters to that service from an external client(not vf page). One way is I append it to the url something like myservice/functionName/parameter1/parameter2. But I want to send them as GET/POST parameters. Does anyone know how to read those parameters in the apex class?

Answer (score 7):

Rather than accept say form encoded parameters it is usually more convenient (for the client and in the Apex code) to accept a JSON string that holds the parameters. For the POST case:

```
@HttpPost  
global static Result post() {
    String jsonString = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
    // Use Apex JSON class to parse
    ...
}
```

For GET parameters you have to do your own string manipulation of the URL that you can obtain from the static field `RestContext.request.requestURI`. (Or better use `params` as Jitendra illustrates.)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to test the REST API below:

```
@RestResource (urlMapping='/wte/test/*')
global class WTE_SampleRESTService {
    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet() {
        String id = RestContext.request.params.get('id');
        System.debug('ID: '+ id);
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost(String id, String name) {
        System.debug('ID: '+id+', Name: '+name);
    }
}
```

You can use [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) or [curl](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/using-curl-with-salesforce-rest-api/).

[image]

above image shows Testing using Workbench

[This post](http://www.webtrafficexchange.com/salesforce-rest-api-example) might be very helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following apex class example will allow you to set parameters in the query string for a post request -

```
@RestResource(urlmapping = '/sendComment/*')

global without sharing class postComment {

@HttpPost
global static void postComment(){

    //create parameters 

    string commentTitle = RestContext.request.params.get('commentTitle');
    string textBody = RestContext.request.params.get('textBody');       

    //equate the parameters with the respective fields of the new record

    Comment__c thisComment = new Comment__c(
        Title__c = commentTitle,
        TextBody__c = textBody, 

    );

    insert thisComment; 


    RestContext.response.responseBody = blob.valueOf('[{"Comment Id": 
    '+JSON.serialize(thisComment.Id)+', "Message" : "Comment submitted 
    successfully"}]');
    }
}
```

The URL for the above API class will look like -

/services/apexrest/sendComment?commentTitle=Sample title&textBody=This is a comment

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off by using the Composite API to achieve this.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm